# Searching a log file

Tags: c++, excel, search, vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching using Regex in VIM or elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6416889/searching-using-regex-in-vim-or-elsewhere)

I'm searching a huge ~600 Mb file for a particular pattern which is 7 Hexadecimal values long. The Problem is

1. the 'pattern' could be on the next line and
2. there are several addressing lines.

I got rid of problem 1 by getting rid of all the carriage returns but I'm still faced with even if the values are on the next line I have no idea how to search past the address line. Below is an example:
`0x000001A0: 36 5B 09 76 99 31 55 09 78 99 34 51 49 BF E0 03`
`0x000001B0: 28 0B 0A 03 0B E0 07 28 0B 0A 03 0B 49 58 09 35`

For example: I want to be able to find the pattern `49 BF E0 03 28 0B 0A`, Which goes across lines 1 and 2 above but I can't just search for it regularly because of the `0x000001B0:` at the beginning of the line Any suggestions or c++ code or excel ideas would be helpful. I'm using VIM at the moment to open this big file and using excel won't open the entire thing.

Comment: What are you looking to do with it? If you just want to view it I think any open source hex viewer will have a search by hex function. If you're looking to do something with it inside a c++ script that's another matter.

Comment: just grep on the terminal or in cygwin if you are running windows?

Comment: A C++ program to read one line at a time, skip over the address, and search that line plus the previous line doesn't seem hard to write. Have you tried?

Comment: @AJG85 does `grep` have a way of searching when the text can cross a line boundary with other arbitrary text in the middle?

Comment: I'm wanting to just view it basically. and from there go through that pattern until I find whwat I need

Comment: @inTide I'm basically wanting to view it what type hex viewer would you suggest that would be capable of opening a ~600Mb file?

Comment: @Mark You might have to do multiple passes but if he's stripping carriage returns and treating it as one line I can't see why not.

Comment: umm...the example you provide is an ASCII text representation of a (supposedly) binary file, hence the first value (before the colon) which gives the numeric offset from the beginning of the file. If you want to search for the hexadecimal values in a binary file, there are better ways to do so than by first converting it into ASCII. Further, are you simply looking for the existence of the seven byte pattern in your data file or are you looking for the offset(s) at which the pattern appears?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python, just read in line, split, chuck the first part, concat the hex into a string, and search. Something like this would work:

```
hex = ""
for each line in lines:
    tmp = line.split() // split on whitespace
    hex += tmp[1:] // grab everything after address

if hex.contains(pattern):
    # do something
```

Or use a regex, but you get the basic idea.

Comment: I thought about providing a Python solution too, but the question specifically asked for C++. I wouldn't have read the entire file before performing the search, it seems inefficient and doesn't retain the addresses which might be necessary to locate the result.

Comment: anyone familiar with a hex viewer that would work? I'm basically wanting to 'view' the pattern throughout the file

Comment: @Tyler31 - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426/what-is-a-good-windows-hex-editor-viewer

Comment: @Steve Thanks for the link. Only question is at point is, being this a "text" file and the viewer not knowing it's supposed to show hex values how do i go about telling it. Hey some of these are hex? I'm looking at XVI32 and it even makes the text somewhere in the file into hex

Comment: Yes, these would work with the binary data that is the source of your text in hand.  Is that no longer available?  The question is a lot easier to answer if you have the original binary data still.

Comment: I do have the original binary data and when opening it I see the values that I need but there are only particular parts of the file indicated by text where I want to thumb through to find the particular pattern I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a circular buffer.

1. Open the file
2. Read a line
3. Read address and discart it
4. Read first value and put it into the buffer
5. Read next value, and throw last value of the buffer (std::list could be good for that)
6. Check if buffer contains the pattern
7. Loop through 5 up to the end of the line
8. Loop through 2 up to the end of the file

Comment: Not what i'm looking to do. sry