# Looking for a Hex Viewer

Tags: search, vim, binary, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Searching a log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413361/searching-a-log-file)

Where I can either enter a binary file or the text file I have and search for a pattern of a multiple hex values.

**What is viewed in my Text File:**

**0x000001A0: 36 5B 09 76 99 31 55 09 78 99 34 51 49 BF E0 03**

**0x000001B0: 28 0B 0A 03 0B E0 07 28 0B 0A 03 0B 49 58 09 35**

For example: I want to be able to find the pattern '49 BF E0 03 28 0B 0A', Which goes across lines 1 and 2 above but I can't just search for it regularly because of the 0x000001B0: at the beginning of the line

Above is what is seen in the text file.

The issue is if it's in binary I'm not sure where I'm located in the file where as if I were in the text file I know what location i'm in (which is necessary).

Needs to be free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use emacs because vim can do it for you (I say this because you tagged this [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), and not to start a flame war).

To do this in vim, open your binary in vim and type the following:

```
:%!xxd
```

This will filter the file and convert to hex mode. So something that looks like this when you open:

```
Êþº¾^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^R^@^@^@^@^@^@^P^@^@^@L0^@^@^@^L^@^@^@^G^@^@^@^C^@^@`^@^@^@
^@^@^L^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^
@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
```

will display as

```
0000000: cafe babe 0000 0002 0000 0012 0000 0000  ................
0000010: 0000 1000 0000 4c30 0000 000c 0000 0007  ......L0........
0000020: 0000 0003 0000 6000 0000 494c 0000 000c  ......`...IL....
```

when you run that command. To convert back to binary form after you're done editing, type:

```
:%!xxd -r
```

Comment: My text file already is in Hex. I don't need it converted "into" Hex. I need to search for a pattern in my text file or in my binary file. Problem that it may overlap over to the next line in which case would run into the 0000010:

Comment: @Tyler31: That is not what your question title suggests, as you can see both answers gave you suggestions for a hex viewer. I guess you could use regex to do what you want, but I think you should post that as a separate question with the tag `regex` so that you get answers from people knowledgable in that area.

Comment: sorry for the incovenience yoda :/

Comment: @Tyler31: No problem. I'm sorry I couldn't be of much help here, as my regex-fu is not particularly strong. I hope you do find a solution for what you want. There is a round-about way of doing it by copying the contents to a temp file, trimming the first 12 characters in each line (i.e., the `0x000001A0: ` part) and then searching... but imo that's very sloppy, and I think you'll get much better answers in the `regex` tag.

Comment: See also `:help hex-editing` in Vim.

Answer (score 0):

I'd honestly recommend [Emacs](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/): you can open up the file and then go **Meta-X hexl-mode** and have a nice hex mode view.

Comment: how do you download things from there?!

Comment: It should just open up in Firefox, and if you are on windows you can download a zip file with the precompiled binaries. If you have a Mac or Linux you should be able to use the ports or apt-get or yum or your package manager to install it.