# How to search through a hex dump using regexes in Vim (or elsewhere)?

Tags: regex, search, vim, binary, hex

I’m looking for a way to search for the text representation of a series of hexadecimal numbers in the hex dump of a binary file that looks like so:

```
0x000001A0: 36 5B 09 76 99 31 55 09 78 99 34 51 49 BF E0 03
0x000001B0: 28 0B 0A 03 0B E0 07 28 0B 0A 03 0B 49 58 09 35
```

The issue is that the pattern *may roll over onto the next line*. For instance, in the above two lines, I wouldn’t be able to immediately search for `03 28 0B` because it spans two lines.

I have been told from recent posting that regex is the way to go, but I’m unfamiliar with it and do not know what to use: Notepad++, Vim, Word, or anything else.

**Edit 1:** The text file that shows the above was derived from a binary file, and I can use Notepad++.

**Edit 2:** To give an example, say I'm trying to get as close to 11:45:00 (military time) as possible. `03 28 0B 0A 03 0B` scattered over the two lines above, can be read as “3 seconds, 40 minutes, 11 hours on the 10th day of March 2011”. I'm looking for a way to go through this file to find how close I can get to 11:45:00.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by a "'text' file"?  Is it a text file, or a binary file?

Comment: Can you use notepad++ or can't? Or you need to use vim only?

Comment: @Andrey Admovich I can use anything really. Just need to be able to view it and zone in on a particular value

Comment: @mwcz text file as in .txt file but it was derived from a binary file.

Comment: What actual task are you trying to accomplish here? There's likely a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me propose the following mappings that take a number of hex digits
from user input or visual selection, create appropriate pattern, and
start a search for it.

```
nnoremap <silent> <expr> <leader>x/ SearchHexBytes('/', 0)
nnoremap <silent> <expr> <leader>x? SearchHexBytes('?', 0)
vnoremap <silent> <leader>x/ :call SearchHexBytes('/', 1)<cr>/<cr>
vnoremap <silent> <leader>x? :call SearchHexBytes('?', 1)<cr>?<cr>

function! SearchHexBytes(dir, vis)
    if a:vis
        let [qr, qt] = [getreg('"'), getregtype('"')]
        norm! gvy
        let s = @"
        call setreg('"', qr, qt)
    else
        call inputsave()
        let s = input(a:dir)
        call inputrestore()
    endif
    if s =~ "[^ \t0-9A-Fa-f]"
        echohl Error | echomsg 'Invalid hex digits' | echohl None
        return
    endif
    let @/ = join(split(s, '\s\+'), '\%(\s*\|\n0x\x\+:\s*\)')
    return a:dir . "\r"
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems none of the more elegant solutions have worked for you so here:

```
\v03(\n[^:]+:)? 28(\n[^:]+:)? 0B(\n[^:]+:)?
```

Yeah, it's copy pasted and super brute forcy but it'd look so much better if I could get friggin backreferences to work.

Just type '/' then copy that pattern in and hit enter, replace 03 28 0B with whatever you need followed by space, new value, then the parenthetical statement. There's roughly a 100% chance there's something better, but I can't think of it.

This will match the memory location as well, but that shouldn't matter if all you want to do is take a peek.

Edit: Forgot about \v

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/) which has a built-in HEX Editor and HEX search. Just open your original binary file, switch to HEX Editor and search for your sequence.

Comment: @Andrey Adamovich the only problem with this is I need to know where I'm at. The reason I've been looking in the Text file is because it has headings I need to search beneath

Comment: but the hex editor shows you the offset if the file and also text representation of the binary data in the same editor view. http://screenshots.en.softonic.com/en/scrn/66000/66559/pspad-editor-7.jpg

Comment: and you can also search for text in the same search window. first find your heading as text and then find your binary sequence

Comment: It won't find my sequence by just entinering it in the control+f box. It says Hex Editor at the bottom of the program

Comment: have you opened the binary file or the text reencarnation of that?

Comment: I don't know then, I can open any binary file easily and search for hex sequences with out problem.